# SQL Query: second most and second least

Tags: sql, database, join

So I have this relation
country(name,code,capital,provice,area,population)

and I would like to find out the second most and second least populous country.

So far, I have this;

```
select name, population
from
(select distinct name, population from country order by population desc limit 2) as A
order by population asc limit 1;
```

where I only get the second most populous country. My problem is proceeding from here, I would love to make a join with an asc in the parentheses and gather the two results, at least that's the only solution I can come up with for this problem. How should I proceed? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This can easily be solved using window functions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the second most populous country, use `limit` with an offset:

```
select name, population
from country c
order by population asc
limit 1 offset 1;
```

To get the second least populated, change the `asc` to a `desc`.  You can do this together using `union all`:

```
(select name, population
 from country c
 order by population asc
 limit 1 offset 1
) union all
(select name, population
 from country c
 order by population desc
 limit 1 offset 1
)
```

Note that if you have only three countries, then this will still return two rows -- with the same country being duplicated.  You can change the `union all` to `union` if you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: Don't know if this is PostgreSQL that's messing with me but I get "HINT: Use separate LIMIT and OFFSET clauses" when I try to execute the first query.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do "Limit 1 Offset 1". Problem solved, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith . . . The question was not tagged with a database so I was using MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Note that this will give you 2+ rows if there are any countries with a tie, whereas limiting the rows will chop off ties.

```
select name, population, '2nd highest' as which
  from country
 where population =
       (select max(population)
          from country
         where population < (select max(population) from country))
union all
select name, population, '2nd lowest' as which
  from country
 where population =
       (select min(population)
          from country
         where population > (select min(population) from country))
```